Baby Rudin Chapter 3 Exercise 14d
I'm working through baby rudin chapter 3 exercises, and I was just curious to see if my proof also works for exercise 14d.
Rudin gives:
$\sigma_n=\frac{s_0+s_1+...+s_n}{n+1}, (n=0,1,2...)$, assume $\{\sigma_n\}$ converges.
$a_n=s_n-s_{n-1}$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}(na_n) = 0$
$s_n - \sigma_n = \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}ka_k$.
Prove that $\{s_n\}$ converges.
The solution guide's proof involves using part (a) to show that if $na_n$ approaches $0$ then the left hand side must as well so $s_n = \sigma_n$ and hence convergence.
Given than $\{s_n\}$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{C}$, is it enough to go from $\lim_{n \to \infty}(na_n) = 0$ to showing that $\{s_n\}$ is Cauchy and are my steps right?
I.e:
$\lim_{n \to \infty}(na_n) = 0 \Rightarrow \forall \varepsilon > 0 \quad \exists N \:\epsilon \:\mathbb{N} \:s.t. \: \forall n \geq N, |n(s_n-s_{n-1})|<\varepsilon \Rightarrow |s_n-s_{n-1}|<\frac{\varepsilon}{n} < \varepsilon$
Let $\varepsilon'> 0$, and choose $n', m' \geq N$. Let's say wlog that $n' > m'$. Then we have:
$|s_{n'}-s_{m'}| = |s_{n'}-s_{n'-1}+s_{n'-1} \:+\: ...\: +\: s_{m'+1} - s_{m'}|$
$\qquad\qquad\:\:\:\leq |s_{n'}-s_{n'-1}| + |s_{n'-1}-s_{n'-2}|\:+\: ...\: +\: |s_{m'+1}-s_{m'}|$
$\qquad\qquad\:\:\:<(n'-m')\frac{\varepsilon'}{n'-m'} = \varepsilon'$ (If we take $\varepsilon =\frac{\varepsilon'}{n'-m'}$)
Does that work and I am allowed to take $\varepsilon$ like that at the end? Thanks.

FYI - use \in to get the "is an element of" symbol: "$\exists N \in \Bbb N$".

Note that in the definition of the limit, an arbitrary $\epsilon$ is chosen first, then an $N$ is picked, dependent on $\epsilon$, then $n$ (and $m$ in your application) are restricted by the $N$ - a restriction that is thus dependent on the chosen value of $\epsilon$. So you cannot choose $\epsilon$ to be dependent on $n', m'$, since you need $\epsilon$ to pick the $N$ that restricts $n', m'$ to regions where the inequality holds.

Thanks Paul. But is it fine if I choose $\varepsilon$ dependent on $n', m'$ because it comes from a separate limit statement? I.e. in the Cauchy part, I choose an arbitrary $\varepsilon'$ first, and I make a different $\varepsilon$ (From my limit definition) dependent on the $n'$ and $m'$ that I have already chosen.

No. The Cauchy condition is "$\forall \epsilon,\exists N, \forall n, m$", not "$\forall \epsilon',\exists N, \forall n, m, \exists \epsilon$". And this is for a reason. The two are not equivalent.
